# ANOVA or T Test and the assumptions in Paper

Tags: anova, t-test, assumptions

I have a question regarding how to use ANOVA appropriately in my paper. The following is my sample data.

[image: Data generated from 5 mice, one "Health" as the control group with 4 treatments]

The mice are randomly selected. The first row is the control group as health mice. There are four treatments applied to the mice.

In my writing, I can run the ANOVA function to generate results, but I am unsure how I should write assumptions about ANOVA. However, I see many papers, lots of authors do not check assumptions. Do I even need to check assumptions and write about them in my paper? Or I will just need to put the results of ANOVA in the paper and explain ANOVA's results?

I know in ANOVA, we have three assumptions:

1. Independence
2. Normality
3. Equality of variances - homogeneity

Same questions/concerns for the t-test. Do I need to describe how the t-test's assumptions are met? For example t-test between "Health" and "Treatment3"?

In many cases, these three assumptions do not meet. When the assumptions do not meet - For the ANOVA alternative, I think I can use Kruskal–Wallis H test. For the t-test alternative, I guess I can use Mann–Whitney U test.

If anyone could give me some sincere opinions about my concerns that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If 'Mouse 1'...'Mouse 5' are five mice which are given the different treatments at different times, then ANOVA might be adequate. If on the other hand you have a total of 25 mice, which are randomly combined with the five treatments, then it does not make sense to speak e.g. of a 'Mouse 1' effect: mouse 1 would not be a particular mouse, but rather five different animals.

I have the feeling that what you are after is the comparison of treatments rather than the mice. If so, a model in which mice are random effects might be preferable to fixed effects ANOVA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. These are 5 mice, not 25. In the actual writing part, do I need to say the ANOVA or t-test assumptions are satisfied? Or I can just use ANOVA or t-test directly without checking the assumptions?

Comment: I would try to be as explicit as possible and give all details.